# Ошибка при добавлении компонента в react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

main.js:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App.jsx';
import AboutPage from './components/AboutPage.jsx';
import { Router , Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Route  path='/about' component={AboutPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('mount-point')
);
```

App.jsx (проблема с компонентов  Link, убираю и все работает):

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router';

const App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <div className="menu-bar">
          <div className="menu-item">
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default App;
```

Ошибки:

```
warning.js?0260:44Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `App`.

invariant.js?568c:38Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `App`.
```

Конфиг webpack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/build',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: "babel",
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader",
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
    },
    {
      test: /\.jpg$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg",
    },
    {
      test: /\.png$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png",
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=26000&mimetype=image/jpg",
    },
    {
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loader: "react-hot!babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react",
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: "json-loader",
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
    },
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Вы не привели код `AboutPage.jsx`. Кстати я такие ошибки дебажу, гораздо быстрее поставить точку, перед объявлением всего, и посмотреть инициализировался ли компонент

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы не правильно импортируете компонент `Link`. Конструкция

```
import Link from `react-router`;
```

Импортирует **все** содержимое библиотеки `react-router` в переменную `Link`. Вместо этого, вам нужно всего лишь вытащить компонент из библиотеки. Вот так:

```
import { Link } from `react-router`;
```